# Float on the bottom of the page without xhtml

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2007

I'm developing on Moss 2007.
I want to create a button the will float on the bottom of the screen. (If I'll scroll down the button will float down. and if I'll scroll up the button will float up.)

I can do it easly with xhtml, but the problem is that I can't change the SharePoint meta tags:

Best Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

### Sticky Footers

I think what you are describing is a **'sticky'** footer. An element on your page which stays rooted to the bottom of the browser window, no matter where the user scrolls to or how long the page is.

There are several resource on the web detailing how to implement a sticky footer, the best of these are detailed below:

- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
- http://css-tricks.com/sticky-footer/
- http://brassblogs.com/blog/sticky-footer
- http://www.waycoolwebdesign.com/Blog/2008/11/15/CSS-Sticky-Footer